# Configure pytest using testpaths to search for tests inside tests folder

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest, pytest-django

I'm trying to improve the test collection speed by including the testpaths option in the pytest.ini file.

Inside each App folder I have a `tests` file where I put my tests, so I'm including it as follows:

```ini
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
```

However, no tests are collected. It returns the error: `ERROR: file or directory not found: tests`

What I'm I missing?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#confval-testpaths), testpaths is a list of directories that should be searched for tests. I don't think this is what you are providing here.

Comment: `testpaths` should be relative to the project root, so if you have a subdirectory `app1/tests`, then `testpaths = tests` won't work. Do a configuration per-app and place one `pytest.ini` with `testpaths = tests` in each of your app directories.

Comment: In my project pytest successfully find tests when a path of the `app1/tests` is not specified. If I set `testpaths = tests`, pytest catch all tests in `./*/tests/test_*.py` subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you should put [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) in the root directly of `django-project` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-my_app1
 |-my_app2
 |-pytest.ini # Here
 └-tests
    |-__init__.py
    └-test_1.py
```

In addition, if the specified [testpaths](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths) below doesn't exist, the tests in `tests` folder are run:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = core.settings
testpaths = my_tests # Doesn't exist
```